# not supporting iOS 13 when submitting to AppStore Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, ios13

In Apple Developer portal, they mention that as of April 2020 we have to support iOS 13, the exact phrase is:

*Starting April, 2020, all iPhone and iPad apps submitted to the App Store will need to be built with the iOS 13 SDK or later. They must also support the all-screen design of iPhone XS Max or the 12.9-inch iPad Pro (3rd generation), or later.*

building with iOS 13 SDK or later ??
can I submit an update to my app before April 2020 that runs on versions below iOS 13 and doesn't support iOS 13 at all?

Comment: Yes, you can you'll get warning for this but will allow it to upload the build but anyway starting from 23rd of December to 27th it's holiday on AppStore

Comment: It says that you must *build with the ios13 sdk*.  This is nothing to do with iOS 13 support; you can only specify the minimum version that you support. Apps always run on newer versions of iOS. I.e. if you specify iOS 10 as the minimum version your app will run on iOS 10, 11, 12 or 13 but not iOS 8 or 9.  Your app may not make specific use of ios13 features, but it will run on iOS 13 regardless of which sdk you use.